# jquery button click changes flashes and goes off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to jquery, and was trying to create a search button. I wanted to append some code to a div on button click, but the changes apply for a second, and goes off (Flashes as if the page is loaded again)

My code as below:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
        <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
        <div id="tfheader">
                <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="">
                        <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120">
                        <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="search" class="tfbutton">
                </form>
        <div class="tfclear"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="container" class="cntnr">
                <p>My text here</p>
        </div>
</body>
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("#search").click(function () {
            console.log('your message');
            $("#container").append('<div><p>Results displayed here</p></div>');
    });

    });
```

Both the console log message and div append get applied for a second and then immediately goes off

Comment: _as if the page is loaded again_ Its correct. The form is submitted thus page reloads. If you don't intend to do so use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is, in fact, reloading because you are submitting the form by clicking on it (*note: this is quite evident since your console clears when you click. Console output typically only clears on reload*). If you don't want to submit the form, you could replace it with a regular button:

```
<input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="search" class="tfbutton">
```

or prevent the default event from triggering:

```
$("#search").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('your message');
  $("#container").append('<div><p>Results displayed here</p></div>');
});
```

---

Demo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('your message');
    $("#container").append('<div><p>Results displayed here</p></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
  <div id="tfheader">
    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="">
      <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120">
      <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="search" class="tfbutton">
    </form>
    <div class="tfclear"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="container" class="cntnr">
    <p>My text here</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change input type from submit to button.

```
<input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="search" class="tfbutton">
```